# Array of JavaScript objects: change value and datatype of one key if condition met

Tags: javascript, mongoose, underscore.js

I'm pulling some data from a MongoDB collection using Mongoose.  I'm getting back my array of objects with just the fields I've selected.  All good.  Here's my code:

```
var fieldsToReturn = 'username password';
User.find({username: {$exists: true}}, fieldsToReturn, {sort: {'created.when': 1}}, function(err, data){
  if (err) {
    return err;
  } else {
    // clever code needed here to manipulate the data!
    return res.json(data);
  }
});
```

What I want to do is iterate through the array of JavaScript objects returned in `data` and if there is a password (it'll be a text string) replace `password` with a boolean `true`, but if it's `null` then return a boolean `false`.

I've tried a bit of underscore.js magic:

```
_.each(data, function(element, index, list){
  if (element.password !== null) {element.password = true};
});
```

But what I get in the JSON that's returned is `"password":"true"` and **not** `"password":true`.  Also tried `element.password = new Boolean(true)`.  Any suggestions?

Comment: OK so Alejandro and Mike, both of the solutions you propose work great on an object literal but both have the same problem as my code in that the result is `"password": "true"` and not `"password": true`.  I wondered whether the issue is more with how Mongoose returns the resulting data so I tried `User.find({userName: {$exists: true}}, fieldsToReturn).sort({'created.when': 1}).lean().exec(function(err, data){...`, the key statement in this chain being `lean()`.  When I do this all works! But I loose the Mongoose middleware, so I'm going to try a few other options here... BRB!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this.

```
data = data.map(function(element) {
  if (element.password) {
    element.password = true;
  }
  return element;
});
```

```js
var data = [
    {
        password: 'secret'
    },
    {
        password: ''
    },
    {
        password: 'swordfish'
    }
];

data = data.map(function(element) {
    if (element.password) {
        element.password = true;
    }
    return element;
});

document.querySelector('pre').innerText = JSON.stringify(data);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [asyncjs lybrary](https://github.com/caolan/async). It will call the callback function when finished all the executions for the array objects. Please, also r[ead carefully](http://book.mixu.net/node/ch7.html) about asyncronous flow in javascript (nodejs) .

Hope it helps!!

```
 //this should work if placed on your clever code and installed asyncjs
 async.map(data, checkPassword, function(err, results){
  //when arrived here, all the array has been checked and modified
  console.log(results);
 }

 //Remember This function must be placed outside of the find() method. 
 function checkPassword(obj, callback)
 {
   if (obj.password) {
   obj.password = true;
   }
   return callback(null, obj);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Mongoose.  Something is happening before the data is returned which makes it look like straight JSON but if you try and manipulate the `element` in a `_.each` loop then the object you're working on (`element`) isn't a simple object mapping to the document in MongoDB.  Any Mongoose experts out there that can shed light on this?

What I did to fix this is use LoDash's `_.mapValues`:

```
function renderUserKeys(obj){
  var newObj = _.mapValues(obj, function(n){return n});
  if (newObj.password !== null) {newObj.password = true};
  return newObj;
};
```

And then in the code:

```
...
} else {
  var newArray = [];
  _.each(data, function(element, index, list){
    newArray.push(renderUserKeys(element._doc)); // note the ._doc
  });
  return res.json(newArray);
};
```

Maybe there is a better function that `_.mapValues` (maybe `_.merge`?) to perform the copy, I'll need to look into this, but for now this works and my Mongoose middleware is still running normally (as I'm *not* using `lean()`).

Lesson learned: Mongoose !== Duck.  As in, it may look like an object but when you try and manipulate it, it doesn't behave as you expect it to!